# Finding All possible Longest Increasing subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I want to find all possible Longest Increasing Subsequences in a given string.

For eg: Given string is `qapbso`

Here the length of longest increasing subsequence is 3.
I want to find all possible longest subsequence of length 3. i.e "abs", "aps", "abo".

I am using Dynamic Programming but I am only getting one LIS. I want to list down all of them.

Comment: if you are specifying a required subsequence length, do you still need to include the notion of 'longest possible'?

Comment: No, I am not specifying the subsequnce length. Here the length of longest LIS is 3, I have just mentioned it for clarity.

Comment: [Sorry I just removed a relevant comment]. You could disable one edge in the graph (see Benoit's answer) at a time, and leave the rest enabled. But yes, it would be one of the most inefficient algorithms of all times...

Comment: izomorphus answer seems to be okay. Have to try it once

Answer (score 5):

So the typical DP solution to this will produce an array in which you know what is the longest possible subsequence starting at a given position i let's say that you have and array with length n in which dp[i] stores the length of the longest non-decreasing subseq that starts with the element with index i.

Now printing all the LNDSS(longest non-decreasing subsequences) is easiest to be done using a recursion. First find the actual length of the LNDSS by seleting the greast value in dp. Next start the recursion from each element in dp that has the maximum value in dp(these may be more then one). The recursion from a given index should print all the sequences starting from the current index that have length equal to the value dp[i]:

```
int st[1000];
int st_index
void rec(int index) {
  if (dp[index] == 1) {
    cout << "Another sequence:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < st_index; ++i) {
      cout << st[i] << endl;
    }
  }
  for (int j = index + 1; j < n; ++j) {
    if (dp[j] == dp[index] - 1 && a[j] >= a[index]) {
      st[st_index++] = a[j];
      rec(j);
      st_index--;
    }
  }
}
```

This is example code in c++(hope it is understandable in other languages as well). I have a global stack called stack that keeps the elements we have already added. It has size 1000 assuming you will never have more then 1000 elements in the LNDSS but this can be increased. The solution does not have the best possible design, but I have focused on making it simple rather then well designed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found this pdf on net. http://www.dei.unipd.it/~geppo/DA2/DOCS/lis.pdf
Please have a look at it. Its not giving the LIS which is ending with same letter

Comment: I posted an answer that puts this inside the usual DP solution for reference.

Answer (score 3):

In 2000 Sergei Bespamyatnikh and  Michael Segal proposed an algorithm for finding all longest increasing subsequences of a given permutation. The algorithm uses a [Van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) and has a time complexity of **O(n + Kl(p))** and space complexity of **O(n)**, where **n** is the length of a permutation **p**, **l(p)** is the length of its longest increasing subsequence and **K** is the number of such subsequences.

See the [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=368941) in the ACM Digital Library or search the web for "Enumerating longest increasing subsequences and patience sorting" to get a free PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Given this graph where all nodes are connected to the nodes that have both higher value and appear later in the sequence of letters of your input string:

[image: graph]

You want to find the longest path from START to END. This is equivalent to the shortest path if all segments have negative length of -1.

Reference on longest path problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: shouldn't this be represented as a directed graph? :P

Comment: It cant be solved by using this technique. It should be directed graph first of all. Then also I can't think of a solution using the technique

Comment: @The Nail: replaced with a graph with arrows.

Comment: This graph is named DAG, and finding longest shortest path or diameter of graph can be done by BFS, there is no need to dijekstra algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate how Ivaylo Strandjev's code works, I put it inside the usual LIS DP solution (in Python). Note: my algo is for **strictly** increasing subsequence.

```py
def lis(a): # assumes a != []
    n = len(a)
    dp = [1 for _ in range(n)] 
    # dp[k] = length of LIS with first element a[k]
    max_length = 1
    for k in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        result = 1
        for i in range(k + 1, n):
            if a[i] > a[k]:
                result = max(result, 1 + dp[i])
        dp[k] = result
        max_length = max(max_length, result)
    
    # printing all LISs
    st = [None for _ in range(max_length)]
    st_index = 0
    def rec(index): # credit: Ivaylo Strandjev
        nonlocal st_index, dp, a
        if dp[index] == 1:
            print("Another sequence:")
            for i in range(st_index):
                print(st[i])
        for j in range(index + 1, n):
            if dp[j] == dp[index] - 1 and a[j] >= a[index]:
                st[st_index] = a[j]
                st_index += 1
                rec(j)
                st_index -= 1
    # beginning the recursion at each valid index
    for index in range(n):
        if dp[index] == max_length:
            st_index = 1
            st[0] = a[index]
            rec(index)
    return max_length
```

If you want to return the LISs instead of printing, simply add a nonlocal list `store` and write `store.append(st.copy())` instead of the printing logic.

If you want to deduplicate LISs that are exactly equal, use a nonlocal set `store` and write `store.add(tuple(st))` instead.